# Namespace error while parsing xml namespace with multiple URIs in perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

```
use XML::LibXML;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Research xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-2_4.xsd" xmlns:rixmldt="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML-datatypes http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-datatypes-2_4.xsd" language="eng"></Research>';

my $respDom = $parser->parse_string($xmldata);
print $respDom;
```

This is the error I get. Does `XML::LibXML` not support multiple URIs in namespaces?

```
Error(s), warning(s):
:1: namespace error : xmlns:schemaLocation: 'http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-2_4.xsd' is not a valid URI
ml.org/2013/2/RIXML http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-2_4.xsd"
                                                                                ^
:1: namespace error : xmlns:rixmldt: 'http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML-datatypes http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-datatypes-2_4.xsd' is not a valid URI
datatypes http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-datatypes-2_4.xsd"
                                                                                ^
```

#### XML reformatted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Research
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML"
    xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-2_4.xsd"
    xmlns:rixmldt="http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML-datatypes http://www.rixml.org/assets/documents/schemas/RIXML-datatypes-2_4.xsd"
    language="eng">
</Research>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying multiple URIs for an XML 1.0 namespace name isn't legitimate syntax. It is hard to imagine what you may mean by it

[Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) says this

> The attribute's normalized value *MUST* be either a URI reference — the namespace name identifying the namespace — or an empty string

Comment: I could not fully understand what you are saying. I can see some validators online which do not throw an error for the above xml but some of them throw.

Comment: @andor: The specification for XML 1.0 allows *a URI reference* and no more. The validators you have found that allow your XML are incomplete and don't verify the namespace properly. What is your meaning when passing two URIs? A namespace abbreviation cannot stand for two namespaces at once!